# javascript problems with swith, case for img & sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I am having some problems with my software I am adding a help sound button.

This is like [image: sound off]

when i click it it like[image: sound on]

When the audio ends it changes to [image: SOUND OFF]

But if i want to replay it, I have to click the button twice.
Why it is so and how to correct it so that i can replay it just with one click

***HTML***

```
<div id="dummy"></div>
<img src="images/soundoff.png" onClick="sound('helpsound.mp3')" id="snd" />
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
 var clickNumber = 2,
 timeoutId = null;

 function sound(soundfile) {
 imagesnd = document.getElementById('snd');

 switch (clickNumber)
 {
  case 1:
        imagesnd.src = "images/soundoff.png";
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="";
        if (timeoutId !== null) 
        {
           clearTimeout(timeoutId);
           timeoutId = null;
        }
        clickNumber = 2
        return(false);
        break;

  case 2:
        clickNumber = 1;                                                                       
        imagesnd.src = "images/sound.png";

        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\"/>";
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
           imagesnd.src = "images/soundoff.png";
           clickNumber = 1;
    },10000);
        clickNumber = 1;
        break;
 }//switch end
 }//function end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I just changed the image not the case so when i clicked it first time it goes to case 1 (nosound) and at second click case 2(sound)

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout duration is set to 10 seconds. Try putting a `console.log` inside your timeout handler to see if it's actually fired and has reset the `clickNumber` back to 1 before you're clicking the image again.

Comment: Thanks!, by putting the console.log i got the prob